# Ошибка No such slot при гет запросе Qt

Tags: c++, qt, get, qtcreator

requests.h

```
#ifndef REQUESTS_H
#define REQUESTS_H

#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkReply>

class Req : public QObject{

public:
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager;
    QNetworkRequest request;
    QNetworkReply *reply;
    sendGet(QString Url);
private slots:
    void getReplyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply);
};

#endif // REQUESTS_H
```

requests.cpp

```
#include "requests.h"
#include <QTextCodec>
#include <QString>
#include <QObject>
#include <QTextCodec>
#include <QString>
#include <QMessageBox>

void Req::sendGet(QString Url)
{   manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(Url);
    //user-agent
    request.setUrl(Url);
    request.setRawHeader("Authorization:", " OAuth AQAAAAAJlF7xAADLW8Sf6NXX-0ugtcoEeY_6dyM");
    request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.setRawHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    reply = manager->get(request);//Получаем данные с сервера
    QObject::connect (
    manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
        this,   SLOT(getReplyFinished(QNetworkReply*))
    );
}

void Req::getReplyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{   qDebug()<<"Task finished";
    QTextCodec* defaultTextCodec = QTextCodec::codecForName("Windows-1251");//Нужная нам кодировка
    QTextDecoder *decoder = new QTextDecoder(defaultTextCodec);
    QString HTML = decoder->toUnicode(reply->readAll());
    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "requests.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    Req req;
    req.sendGet("https://cloud-api.yandex.net/v1/disk/");
}
```

При нажатии на кнопку получаю:

```
QObject::connect: No such slot QObject::getReplyFinished(QNetworkReply*) in ..\secured_yad\requests.cpp:21
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
```

Пытался сделать как сказано здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29211085/qt-no-such-slot-qobjectslotnameqnetworkreply ,
но видно сделал не верно.

Comment: Приваьный slot?

Comment: Добавьте `Q_OBJECT` внутрь объявления класса `Req`. Для чего это надо: чтобы Qt узнал про ваши слоты, нужен дополнительный код, генерируемый утилитой `moc` во время сборки. Эта утилита пробегает по всем файлам проекта, но обрабатывает только классы с `Q_OBJECT` внутри.

Comment: Добавил Q_Object ничего не поменялось

Comment: Хотя нет вру, QObject::connect: No such slot QObject::getReplyFinished(QNetworkReply*) in ..\secured_yad\requests.cpp:21 ушла, остальные остались(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение проблемы со слотом предоставил [Arhad](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/208074/arhad): необходимо добавить в класс Q_OBJECT и запустить qmake, проблема с ssl решается путём добавления в папку к исполняемому файлу проекта libeay32.dll, libssl32.dll, ssleay32.dll